# XCode 6.3 Dependency Analysis Warning

Tags: xcode

I'm using XCode 6.3 and I randomly got a "Dependency Analysis Warning: warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "arm64")." when I try to Archive my project.

Everything I've read on how to fix this does not seem to apply to XCode 6.3. In my project settings under Architecture I only have two options to work with: Base SDK which has the options of iOS 8.3 and (Latest) iOS 8.3, and Build Active Architecture Only which has the options of Yes, No, and Other.

So how did this randomly change and how do I include the armv7 architecture in the current version of xcode?

Thanks!